# jQuery: jsonFlickrFeed not working

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

I am trying to call my photos in flicker so I could use them in my photo gallery.

But my code does not retrieve anything.

I watched it from lynda.com I included this line of code

```
<script src="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=[MY_ID]&format=json&tags=viewsource">
```

Note [My_ID] = of course my ID.

When I run it in my browser it shows the jsonFlickrFeed completely with the objects.

However, when I call it in my script

```
function jsonFlickrFeed(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

Nothing shows up in my console. I need to retrieve the photos so I could display them in my gallery. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method, that also has an example to fetch photos from flicker.

```
var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
 $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
   tags: "mount rainier",
   tagmode: "any",
   format: "json"
 })
 .done(function( data ) {
  $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
    $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
    if ( i === 3 ) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's working, however I cannot filter the photos correctly. I already added user_id. But it always get the recent uploads I don't know why

Comment: its depands on sent data by flicker and filter method by you.

Comment: I a added user_id inside the json for filter and I put in my user_id: {my_id}
I think that's enough filter to only get my photos right? Well if it is, it's not working

Comment: My fault, I included my ID inside the flickerAPI variable. This one worked. Thanks a lot man.